# Loop multiple lists based on their length

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, list, sorting

In my code I have 6 lists of objects of different sizes.

I need to go through them all in a specific order, from the smallest list to the largest.

```
var list_1 = [...]    // length 24
var list_2 = [...]    // length 4
var list_3 = [...]    // length 3
var list_4 = [...]    // length 4
var list_5 = [...]    // length 11
var list_6 = [...]    // length 2

// Need code here for loop each list in order asc
list_6.forEach(...)   // length 2
list_3.forEach(...)   // length 3
list_2.forEach(...)   // length 4
list_4.forEach(...)   // length 4
list_5.forEach(...)   // length 11
list_1.forEach(...)   // length 24
```

Does anyone have a simple solution ? Thanks

Comment: Add the lists to a list and sort that list by the length of its elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add the lists in an array, sort it and perform the loop

```
[list, list2, ...]
    .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
    .forEach(array => array.forEach(...))
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the lists into another list and sort them.

```js
const list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
  list2 = [1],
  list3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

let listOfLists = [list1, list2, list3].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);

console.log(listOfLists);
listOfLists.forEach(list => {
  list.forEach(itemInList => {
    console.log(itemInList);
  });
});
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zc2edd?file=src/app/app.component.ts) example.

Comment: You can post the code here and [create a runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992). If the external link is deleted or modified, the answer will have no future value

Comment: Also `[this.list1, this.list2, this.list3].sort()` is wrong and doesn't work

Comment: You are right, I was too hasty. I've updated the example!